# Microsoft Edge browser has issues while automating drop down using selenium

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

For a recent client requirement we're trying to automate a web application using Microsoft Edge browser. The drop down element has id and name using which it can be clicked. But when we use "Select" class to select the value, it throws an exception "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException". I'm trying to execute using RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: Make sure to attach the exception with the message and stacktrace and the source code.

Comment: If you post the error or can supply code showing the specific issue, i'd be happy to try and help